# Error integrando pasarela de pago Redsys mediante API PHP

Tags: php

Saludos comunidad. Estoy terminando una tienda virtual y estoy integrando la pasarela de pago a la tienda. La pasarela de pago es Redsys, ya he integrado y procesado pagos y todo a ido bien, he probado varias veces y bien. Ahora el problema que tengo es que cuando paso a la pasarela de pagos a meter los datos de la tarjeta me aparece un monto que no es el de mi carrito de compras, adjuntare dos imágenes mostrando lo que me esta pasando.

Esta es la imagen de el resumen de mi carrito de compras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es ya en la pasarela de pago:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, el monto total no es el mismo, el de mi carrito es 225 y en la pasarela de pago me aparece 2,25. De verdad no consigo la manera de arreglar esto. Si alguien tiene conocimiento acerca de esto le agradecería muchísimo la ayuda, aclaro que todo esto lo tengo en modo de prueba aún.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si revisas la documentación encontrarás lo siguiente:

> **Ds_Merchant_SumTotal**: Obligatorio. Representa la suma total de los importes de las cuotas. **Las dos últimas posiciones se consideran decimales**.

Las dos últimas posiciones se consideran decimales, por lo que para un valor de 225, se debe enviar 22500, es decir añadir los decimales siempre, pero sin la coma o punto.

Comment: Gracias Xeriff. Ya me fije. Solo tenia que multiplicar mi monto total * 100. Muchas gracias